# Matlab: How fork another thread to load data while the main thread keep on doing the major task?

Tags: multithreading, matlab

I have many cached data batches, each size is about 2GB. So what I can do is simply

```
% loading data (about 2 min)
% process data (about 4 min)
```

It's very slow because the process function always needs to wait matlab to load data. 
Here's the question, how to let matlab pre-load the next batch when processing the current data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a JAVA thread to load the data. See [this](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/explicit-multi-threading-in-matlab-part1) example on the [undocumented MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com) blog.

Comment: I didn't know matlab can do that! Thank you!

Comment: You welcome. If you find my answer useful, please accept it.